# twitter bootstrap modal popup appearing 3 times in rails 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using twitter bootstrap modal popup. I don't know why it is loading 3 times.
In application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

_modal.html.erb

```
<div id ="mymodal">
bootstrap modal popup code
</div>
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#mymodal').html("<%=j render 'layouts/modal', template: 'partial_file', title: 'Add' %>");
$('#mymodal .modal').modal();
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the question. What does "loading 3 times" mean? Does it appear and disappear 3 times?

Comment: modal popup appearing 3 times

Comment: When the modal appears three times, inspect the page source and search for ".modal()". Maybe there are three different ".modal()" calls.

Comment: <%= link_to "Add More",posts_path, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
when i click on Add More it is appearing 3 times and I inspect the source code  mymodal div  is present only once.
That too appearing 3 times when i'm coming from other pages. But when I refresh and click on Add More then it is appearing one time.

Comment: Could you post all of your erbs? (html, js, and any other partial if used)

Comment: _modal.html.erb
<div id ="mymodal">
bootstrap modal popup code
</div>
posts/index.html.erb
<%= link_to "Add More",new_post_path, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-primary' %> 

posts/new.js.erb
$('#mymodal').html("<%=j render 'layouts/modal', template: 'partial_file', title: 'Add' %>");
$('#mymodal .modal').modal();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88994/discussion-between-sunny-and-1-44mb).